# vba applying format for table column

Tags: excel, vba, format, listobject

I am trying to apply a currency format to a specific column in a table.
I am trying 2 options:

```
Sheet1.ListObjects("MyTaqble").ListColumns("Balance").Style = "Currency"
```

And:

```
Sheet1.ListObjects("MyTaqble").ListColumns("Balance").NumberFormat = _
    "_([$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_);_([$€-x-euro2] * (#,##0.00);_([$€-x-euro2] * ""-""??_);_(@_)"
```

For both I get the following error:
Object doesn't support this property or method

What is the right way to apply format to a table column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood you would like to do something like that

```
Sub FormatIt()
Dim v As ListColumn
    Set v = Sheet1.ListObjects("MyTaqble").ListColumns("Balance")
    v.Range.Style = "Currency"
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub FormatItA()
Dim v As ListColumn
    Set v = Sheet1.ListObjects("MyTaqble").ListColumns("Balance")
    v.Range.NumberFormat = _
    "_([$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_);_([$€-x-euro2] * (#,##0.00);_([$€-x-euro2] * ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You need to apply the style (or numberformat) to the **`Range`** property of the `ListColumns` object.

So:

```
Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Balance").Range.Style = "Currency"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Range, I would use `DataBodyRange`. This will prevent any changes to the header row of the table.

```
Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Balance").DataBodyRange.Style = "Currency"
```